# How to add command to VS Code language extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I made a TextMate grammar for my programming language, which I want to publish as VS Code extension. Now, I want to add a command to open a preview on the right, but as soon as I add `"main": "./out/extension.js"`, the grammar stops working; there's no syntax highlighting, no error message, and the language is nowhere to be found.

I am at a loss and have no idea why this happens. The debugger doesn't display anything, even when I add a breakpoint for uncaught exceptions. And what I find most confusing is that the script I set as `main` doesn't seem to be executed either: It registers commands (following [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/webview-sample/README.md)), but the commands don't show up in the command palette.

Here's my `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "name": "pomsky-vscode",
  "displayName": "Pomsky",
  ...
  "activationEvents": [
    "onWebviewPanel:pomskyPreview"
  ],
  "main": "./out/extension.js",
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "pomsky.openPreview",
        "title": "Open compiled RegExp on the right",
        "category": "Pomsky"
      }
    ],
    "languages": [
      {
        "id": "pomsky",
        ...
        "configuration": "./language-configuration.json"
      }
    ],
    "grammars": [
      {
        "language": "pomsky",
        "scopeName": "source.pomsky",
        "path": "./syntaxes/pomsky.tmLanguage.json"
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

When I remove `activationEvents` and `main`, the syntax highlighting works again.

Comment: do you need to add `"onCommand:pomsky.openPreview"` to the `activationEvents`? https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/command#creating-a-user-facing-command

Comment: I tried that, then got the warning that it isn't required because VS Code infers this automatically now. But I just found the answer: `yo code` generated `"engines": { "vscode": "^1.76.0" }`, but I'm still using version 1.75 

Comment: If you don't actual have a file `./out/extension.js`, that's the expected behavior. To make a complete extension with commands and syntax, you need to merge the hello world sample with your syntax files, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/helloworld-sample

Comment: @LexLi I do have a `./out/extension.js` and set up everything correctly. Only problem was that the VSCode version was incompatible. Changing the `engines` field made it work. See my comment above.

Comment: Then you should post/accept your own answer below to end the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the `engines` key was incorrect. `yo code` auto-generated this part, and used the latest VS Code version (1.76), even though I'm still on VS Code 1.75. Changing the version fixed the problem.